# Modify the wordpress admin bar to add custom messages

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to convert the Wordpress admin bar into something more useful for the registered users. My client has asked me to add into that bar a space to display instant messages that will appear for a few seconds and then dissapear. The idea is that this space will allow the users who are online to see if someone is messaging them like a chat.

```
class MessageMenu{
    function MessageMenu(){
        add_action( 'admin_bar_menu', array( $this, 'message_section' ) );
    }

    function add_message( $message, $timeout = 2000 ){
        // This function should add a new live message to the admin bar
        // First it should check if there is a current message
        // Then write the new message
        global $wp_admin_bar;
    }

    function message_section(){
        // This function will supposedly create a 
        global $wp_admin_bar;
        $args = array(
            'id'    => 'message_section',
            'title' => __( 'Mensajes' ),
            'parent'=> false,
            'href'  => false,
            'group' => true );
        $wp_admin_bar->add_node( $args );
        $this->add_message( 'Live messages' );
    }
}

function MessageMenuInit(){
    global $MessageMenu;
    $MessageMenu = new MessageMenu();
}
add_action( 'init', 'MessageMenuInit' );
```

Comment: What's the problem? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Your description makes me think that this needs to be Javascript/AJAX, not PHP. You won't get any new messages except on page load if you use PHP, and that doesn't really sound like "messaging ... like a chat"